# How to give subquery a name

Tags: postgresql

I have a query like following but not working:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) as count,  a.COUNT(*) AS total
FROM A
WHERE key IN  (SELECT key
                FROM B
                WHERE condition
               ) a
GROUP BY key;
```

I also hope to get the total number result in

```
(SELECT key
 FROM B
 WHERE condition
)
```

How can I give it a label, and use it in outer Select? Or any other methods? Thanks?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for would be a `Left Join`

```
SELECT a.key, sum(b.bCount) as count,  a.COUNT(*) AS total
FROM A
LEFT JOIN  (
   SELECT key, COUNT(1) as bCount
   FROM B
   WHERE condition
) b
on A.key = b.key
GROUP BY key;
```

Comment: Which key? Needs the table alias a.key in select and group by clauses

Comment: I don't think it is right, the result of LEFT JOIN cannot make sure every A.key = b.key ?

Answer (score 0):

If I properly understand your goal:

```
with 
  a1 as (select key, count(*) as cnt from a group by key),
  b1 as (select key, count(*) as cnt from b where condition group by key)
select
  a1.key, a1.cnt, b1.cnt
from
  a1 join b1 on (a1.key = b1.key)
```

Answer (score 0):

In PG [identifiers are case-insensitive](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS). So in your query table `A` and sub-query `a` are the same thing to the server and that is not possible. In fact, the table is probably called `a`, even if you did `CREATE TABLE A (...)`. Only if you double-quoted the table name upon creation, like `"A"`, will the case be preserved, but then you should also double-quote the table name in all queries. Giving a different label to the sub-query or double-quoting the table name will make the error go away.

In your sub-query you need to do the counting if you want that information available in the main query. Instead of the correlated sub-query - `key IN ...` - you should make two sub-queries (because they group over different relations that are likely to be dissimilar) and `JOIN` them in the main query:

```
SELECT key, sub1.count, sub2.total
FROM (
  SELECT key, count(*) AS count FROM a
  GROUP BY key ) sub1
JOIN (
  SELECT key, count(*) AS total FROM b
  WHERE condition
  GROUP BY key ) sub2 USING (key);
```